# WooCommerce set_height() Not Working as Expected

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've got a WooCommerce site with existing products. Currently, the products have no dimensions, and I'm looking to update each product's dimensions by ID programmatically. I thought I could use set_height() to do this, but it's not working as I expected.

Here's my code in functions.php for quick testing:

```
$_product = new WC_Product(1234);
var_dump($_product);
$_product->set_height('2');
echo $_product->get_height();
```

This appears to be working based on the var_dump and the get_height() echo statement. The var_dump is the correct product info and the number that is output from the echo statement is "2". However, this doesn't seem to actually save the product data. After running this code and then viewing the product, it does not have a height value of 2 as it should, instead it's just blank as it was before.

I'm pretty lost here, any ideas on how to get it to actually update the product's height?

Thanks.

Comment: If you add $_product->save(); after you set the height, does it make any difference?

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 2 ways to update product dimensions like height in your case:

1) Using the **`WC_Product`** setter methods + `save()` method:

```
$_product = wc_get_product(1234); // Get an instance of the WC_Product object

$_product->set_height('2'); // Set your new height

$_product->save(); //  <==  <==  Save the new data set in your product
```

2) Using `update_post_meta()` from the product ID:

```
 update_post_meta( 1234, '_height', 2 );
```

Comment: Adding $product->save(); is what I was missing, thanks!